# Android Action Bar Spinner Item

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I implemented an Action Bar spinner in my application, and it does display the selected of the two values I added to the ArrayAdapter associated with it.  However, I was surprised that when I touch the spinner item (and select one of the Adapter members), the OS doesn't call onOptionsItemSelected().

I don't know WHY I assumed that it would, in retrospect, but it certainly seems to me that it should.  Can can anyone tell me if there is a way to FORCE a call to onOptionsItemSelected() in this situation -- or if this is the way it's supposed to work and I'm just going to have to find a different way to accomplish the functionality??

Finally, I'm not using Action Bar Sherlock -- before this it didn't seem necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to have a look at is..

```
ActionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(SpinnerAdapter adapter, OnNavigationListener callback)
```

You'll be running this in your onCreate code. As well as passing it your ArrayAdapter, you can pass in an OnNavigationListener on the above to handle the clicks on your ActionBar spinner.

Comment: I added (I think) what you suggested to my onCreate(): ab.setListNavigationCallbacks (myAdapter, this).  Because I set the callback to "this", I needed to add "implements OnNavigationListener" to my class declaration (public class blah blah blah...).  Once I did that, I needed to define onNavigationItemSelected() in my class, which I did, and which only has a Log command at this point.  Sadly, the method is not being called.  By any chance, can you point me at an example??